# Show the nearest week day after today from a given string in php

Tags: php

I am in a puzzle right now. I have searched but didnt find any good clue for this. Or I am too fool to make this happen.

I have a list of week days.

```
$marks = "mon,wed,fri";

$solve_date = The NEXT day of week after today from $marks.
```

So, since today is `mon`, the `$solve_date` should be `wed` here.

Any help??

I was just able to determine if today is listed on the given string..
I used this

```
in_array($today_in_week_day, $marks)
```

Comment: Get names of following days and check if they are in `$marks`

Comment: @u_mulder thank you so much.. I think I can compare this now..